# Convert money input into coins

Tags: c#

ive just started some classes on c# and have been given an assignment with the following rules:
 Prompt the user to enter an amount of dollars and cents. For example 1.18
- Display the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies to make that amount

Example If they entered 2.16 it should say:
8 quarters, 1 dimes, 1 nickels, 1 pennies

the problem that i run into is that this only seems to work if they type the money value as a whole. so if they wanted to type $1.18 they would type 118 and it would work just fine, but as soon as they type 1.18 it crashes. another example would be if they were to type 765 for $7.65 it would work fine, however if they type it correctly as 7.65 it would fail. sorry for the lame question, im super new, thanks for the help!

````
         int totalCash;
            Console.WriteLine("input money");
            string moneyString = Console.ReadLine();
            totalCash = int.Parse(moneyString);
            int quarter = totalCash / 25;
            totalCash %= 25;
            int dime = totalCash / 10;
            totalCash %= 10;
            int nickel = totalCash / 5;
            totalCash %= 5;
            int penny = totalCash / 1;
            totalCash %= 1;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} quarters, {1} dimes, {2} nickels, {3} pennies", quarter, dime, nickel, penny);
           ```
````

Comment: Start by always using the `TryParse` versions.  Users will always find ways to crash your perfect programs

Comment: If you want to allow them to enter decimal values use `decimal.Parse` instead (or even `decimal.TryParse` to handle non-numeric entries) and just multiply that by 100 to get it to cents.  And you probably want to round that in case they enter 2.657.

Comment: _it crashes_ - Can you elaborate how "it crashes"? What is exception message? What is the line where application throws an exception? Without such information all answers will be simple guessing of what can go wrong

Comment: @Fabio It's pretty obvious what will go wrong when you do `int.Parse` on a string like "2.16".  However OP should be in the habit of adding the exception info in general.

Comment: if the user were to input a decimal it would respond "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @michaelbrunes An integer is a whole number. 2.16 is not a whole number. Valid whole numbers around 2.16 are: 2 and 3.

Comment: @juharr, goal of my comment were that if OP would write detailed answer he would find solution by itself ;)

Comment: `int totalCash = (int)(decimal.Parse(moneyString) * 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working when you enter whole number should be the clue you pay attention to.  If you assume the whole number is dollars, you can not mod by a whole number.  All of your divisors are a factor of 100 too big.  When you do that, you'll notice that you have the wrong data type as well.  Note that i disagree with using tryparse when debugging as it eats errors.  You should be running it in debug mode and then you would get an actual stack trace and a line it crashes at.

Comment: This would be better as a comment.

Comment: that's your opinion and you're welcome to it, but i disagree that solving the question belongs in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways get the result but this the best approach I ever tried :

```
public static string ConvertMoneyIntoCoins(double money)
    {
        int cents = (int)(Math.Round(money, 2) * 100);

        var coins = new[] {
                            new { Name = "Quarters", Value = 25 }, new { Name = "Dimes", Value = 10 },
                            new { Name = "Nickels", Value = 5 }, new { Name = "Pennies", Value = 1 } 
                         };

        var changes = coins.Select(coin => new { Amt = Math.DivRem(cents, coin.Value, out cents), Coin = coin }).Where(x => x.Amt != 0).ToList();

        var strBld = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var change in changes)
        {
            strBld.Append(change.Amt + " " + change.Coin.Name + ", ");
        }

        return strBld.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone! looks like pretty much everyone here told me how to fix it, i just had to google some of the terminology for any of it to make sense (literally my second day coding), I also didint realize i could parse and cast and multiply all in the same line of code. I was trying it on multiple lines and i guess i just wasn't doing it correctly.  thanks again for all your help, you rock!

Comment: I had to upvote this just because of how neat it is.